# ESP32 cannot bypass Firewall

Tags: windows-10, arduino

I am using [ESP32](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/esp32-thing-hookup-guide) (which is Arduino based microcontroller with  to connect to a Unity game I am building on my PC. I am using the PC as a WiFi Hotspot and the ESP32 is connecting to that hotspot using a hardcoded password. However, when it is connected the board's packets are blocked by my firewall (Windows 10 default Windows Defender Firewall). It works fine once I turn it off. How do I make it so that the UDP packets from the esp32 can bypass the firewall without me needing to completely turn it off?

Comment: This is not specific enough on how exactly it is connected (which port?) but for general firewall configuration to allow specific inbound connections see for example [How To Open Firewall Ports In Windows 10](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-open-firewall-ports-in-windows-10,36451.html).

Comment: consider using websockets so that you don't need to mess around with port settings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the UPD port needed for it to correctly communicate and open that in inbound your Firewall. In some configurations I've seen, the default port was UDP 5001.